# Problem trying to get column with more 0´s

Tags: r

im using R and im trying to get the column name of the column that has more 0´s ,
I have this function:

```
preguntasMenosRespondidas<-function(){ 

  tablaPreguntas = select(data1, c(8:79))
  //ANSWER HERE
 }
preguntasMenosRespondidas()
```

and the data frame (tablaPreguntas) look like this (the real data frame has like 13krows):

[dataframe here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2crl2.png)

What i need to do if i need that the function return me '2.3'

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please make sure to share a reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Screenshots are not good because we cannot use them to copy-paste the data and try to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get the column that has the maximum number of zeros:

```
which.max(apply(data1[,8:79], 2, function(col) sum(col==0)))
```

You can wrap this in a function if you want, but I don't think you need to or want to:

```
preguntasMenosRespondidas <- function() { 
    tablaPreguntas = select(data1, c(8:79))
    which.max(apply(tablaPreguntas, 2, function(col) sum(col==0)))
  }
preguntasMenosRespondidas()
```